# p:selectOneListbox Scroll to Pre-Selected Item

Tags: primefaces

In `PF8.0`, I have the following snippet:

```
<p:selectOneListbox widgetVar="wgtListBox" filterMatchMode="contains" filter="true" value="#{serviceController.city.id}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{cityController.cities}" var="city" itemLabel="#{city.name}" itemValue="#{city.id}"/>
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

The list has about 20 cities.

When the user selects the city the first time (by typing and/or scrolling), the logic makes sense.
However, when the page loads with a pre-selected item that the user might wish to modify, I would like that selected item to be scrolled-to. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your listbox a widgetVar like this..

```xml
<p:selectOneListbox widgetVar="wgtListBox" ..
```

Then open F12 in Chrome console and type this...

```js
PrimeFaces.scrollInView(PF('wgtListBox').listContainer,
                        PF('wgtListBox').jq.find('.ui-state-highlight'));
```

That uses Javascript to scroll to the focused item.

Comment: Any solution that works is a good soluton!  I will update my answer

Comment: I have updated the solution thanks for pointing that out.